# Can I pass an object's property along with the object to work on?

Tags: c#

I have a sequential filter on an `IQueryable<Person>` using an instance of my `Person` class, running like so:

```
    public IQueryable<Person> FilterPeopleOnPersonCriteria(IQueryable<Person> people, Person p)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.FirstName))
        {
            people = people.Where(x => x.FirstName == p.FirstName);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Surname))
        {
            people = people.Where(x => x.Surname == p.Surname);
        }
        // etc. for all Person's string properties

        return people;
    }
```

I'm figuring I can DRY myself off and replace the repetitions of if/else if I could pass the `people`, the `Person` and which `property` I'd like to apply the filter to, to a specific filter method, something like this:

```
    public IQueryable<Person> FilterPeopleOnProperty(IQueryable<Person> people, Person p, Person.Property personProperty)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.personProperty))
        {
            people = people.Where(x => x.personProperty == p.personProperty);
        }
        return people;
    }
```

SO in the end my original query would just look like:

```
    public IQueryable<Person> FilterPeopleOnPersonCriteria(IQueryable<Person> people, Person p)
    {
        people = FilterPeopleOnPersonProperty(people, p, new Person().FirstName);
        people = FilterPeopleOnPersonProperty(people, p, new Person().Surname);
        // etc. for all properties on p
        return people;
    }
```

I'm assuming this would be possible using some Generic Types and new instances of my `Person` class but have no real idea where to start.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but why wouldn't you just concatenate your conditions using `&&` ?

Comment: Ok, I don't want the logic inside there to confuse the question, I'll remove it to try and simplify.

Comment: You might save 2 lines of code here, but you'd most likely add at least five times that for using introspection to find the `PropertyInfo` class on the object.

Comment: @fredrik the filtering is just an example. I had more complex filtering but I think it was confusing the real question. It would also mean I can amend the filtering by just changing one method and not have to go through each property and change each line.

Comment: Why don't you club the conditions together using && operator. That would be performance efficient !

Comment: You could use reflection to compare or you could use expressions to call the "IsNullOrEmpty" and also to compare the properties

Answer (score 1):

I guess that that's what you're looking for:

```
namespace Extensions
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, bool condition, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return condition ? collection.Where(predicate) : collection;
        }
    }
}
```

We simply do the filtration only if the condition was true. I used `IEnumerable<T>` since that's more generic and is implemented by `IQueryable<T>` anyway, but you could still use `IQueryable<T>` instead. If you want to use `IQueryable<T>` instead, you're gonna need to use `System.Linq.Expressions`, and replace `Func<T, bool>` with `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

A use-case similar to yours would look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> FilterPeople(IEnumerable<Person> people, Person person)
{
    return people.WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.FullName), p => p.FullName == person.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Ahah, predicates, I remember reading about those a while back. I actually have a lot more filtering occurring but this looks like a promising start.

Comment: In case of `IQueryable<T>`, I think you need to use `Expression<Func<...>>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you are asking right, you want to pass a Person object where some (string) properties are filled like "Starts*", "*ends", "ExactValue" and you use that Person as a base for QBE (Query By Example. ie:

```
Person p = new Person {FirstName="S*", LastName="*doe", Country="USA"};
```

Would do a search like:

```
people.Where(p => p.FirstName.StartsWith("S") &&
                  p.LastName.EndsWith("doe") &&
                  p.Country == "USA");
```

right? If so, then I think you could utilize [Scott Gu's dynamic Linq](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) which some good people made available on NuGet and [documented here](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).

Here is some sample code for your case using that Nuget lib (System.Linq.Dynamic):

```
public IQueryable<Person> FilterPeopleOnPersonCriteria(IQueryable<Person> people, Person p)
{
    var t = p.GetType();
    var fields = t
        .GetFields()
        .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(string) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)t.GetField(x.Name).GetValue(p)))
        .Select(x => x.Name);
    foreach (var f in fields)
    {
        var fi = t.GetField(f);
        string pVal = (string)fi.GetValue(p);
        if (pVal.Contains('*'))
        {
            var query = $"{f}.{(pVal.StartsWith("*") ? "Ends" : "Starts")}With(@0)";
            people = people.Where(query, pVal.Replace("*", ""));
        }
        else
        {
            var query = $"{f} == @0";
            people = people.Where(query, pVal);
        }
    }
    return people;
}
```

You would call it like:

```
var personQBE = new Person {
                  FirstName="J*",
                  LastName="Doe"
                });  

var result = FilterPeopleOnPersonCriteria(people, personQBE);
```